# Is [instagram] useful?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

I just found the [instagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instagram) tag. Now seeing as there is also the [instagram-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instagram-api) tag I feel like the [instagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instagram) one should be removed or synonymized to the API version of the tag, as that is the one that seems to be programming related.

I do not know the proper method of requesting this, so I just posted here.

What do you guys think?

Also I don't know if it is appropriate to add this in here but there is also the [facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook) and [twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter) tags that do not seem totally useful. Maybe the [facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook) one, but definitely not the [twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter) one.

Comment: I agree with you, it is not only incoherent but also creates doubt about the question itself.

Comment: Given the title I would down vote: *No, Instagram is not useful* but I see this about the tag....

Comment: We have to cleanup the tag before it can be synonymized. For example, specific question about scraping instagram should not end up the with api tag. Ex: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27881430/java-extracting-instagram-likes), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130499/how-to-scrape-instagram-with-beautifulsoup), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25359247/casperjs-bind-issue), [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711340/would-it-be-feasible-to-use-something-like-phantomjs-to-log-in-to-instagram-com) only to show a few. Those should lose the tag.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Then would you say remove the tag from these questions, or are you saying keep the tag?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Ninja edit

Comment: "Is Instagram useful?" No, I don't think so. ...Oh, you mean the _tag_ for it; I see.

Comment: It has been useful to tag two and a half thousand questions.  And find @krisrak, an expert that answered many of them.  SO has a very long tail, you don't have to know or like what is on the far end of it.

Comment: @HansPassant maybe so but its not exactly a good tag, maybe just make it so the api version is synonymized into the normal one, like the twitter and facebook ones. The api tag is useful the catch all one not exactly so IMHO.

Answer (score 57):

> "Is [Instagram] useful?"

No.

Considering we already have the [instagram-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instagram-api) tag, and considering that Instagram is not a programming tool or application, the [instagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instagram) tag does not belong on this site. Questions with it should either be re-tagged as [instagram-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instagram-api) or closed.

Comment: It looks like both `twitter` and `facebook` do it the other way around where their `-api` tags link to the plain tags instead.

Comment: @BSMP I was not answering from the perspective of making it a synonym, rather just removing it/re-tagging. Even so, the behavior you describe for Twitter & Facebook is wrong, in my opinion; improper tags should link to proper ones, not vice versa.

Comment: @BSMP I saw that on second look, do you think they should be changed to work the other way around?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder - I think it should be consistent but if the existing synonyms can be flipped, that would make more sense.

Comment: @BSMP I thought so too, would it make sense to create a new question on this?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I don't think so; I doubt the existing synonyms will be flipped. There's effectively like 100,000 questions with those tags and none with the synonyms.

Comment: @TylerH fair enough :)

Comment: I disagree, there are very interesting nuances about the instagram website which scrapers and other scripts can utilize. but they may not be specific to instagram and maybe more about React or some other web framework. Anyway, my opinion isn't concrete enough to write my own separate answer about it.

Comment: @CQM I don't think those merit questions about Instagram on Stack Overflow, let alone an Instagram tag.